# tf.Data.Dataset - On each Epoch, only train with a sub sample of the full dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an image dataset with a large imbalance of positive and negatives samples (many more negatives). I would like to create a tf.data.Dataset where each epoch it will train with all of the positive samples but only (ratio * len(positive) ) of the negative samples.

I am currently using a datagen inherited from keras.util.Sequence to achieve this and using this subsampling policy is performing much better than training on all data.

However reading the docs on Dataset, I cannot seem to find a way to do it, is it possible?

In my existing data generator, I am doing this:

```py
# List if indicies of the positive and negative samples
positives = np.where(self.labels == 1)[0]
negatives = np.where(self.labels == 0)[0]
# How many of the negatives do we want to use?
n_negatives = np.clip(int(len(positives) * self.config.DATASET_NEGSUBSAMPLE_RATIO), 1, len(negatives))
# Choose random negatives
subsampled_negatives = np.random.choice(negatives, n_negatives, replace=False)
# Create the incidies array from the positive and subsamples negative indicies
self.indexes = np.concatenate((positives, subsampled_negatives))
# Shuffle them together
np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

Comment: Maybe useful for you, there exist [`tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets) (example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data)) and [`tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/rejection_resample) (to use with [`apply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#apply)), which may help you control the prevalence of each class in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`positives` and `negatives` are defined as in the question.

```
positives = [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]
negatives = [(10,0),(11,0),(12,0),(13,0),(14,0),(15,0),(16,0)]

NEGATIVE_SAMPLES = 3

pos_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(positives)
neg_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(negatives).shuffle(1000)

ds = pos_ds.concatenate(neg_ds.take(NEGATIVE_SAMPLES)).shuffle(1000)

els = [v.numpy().tolist() for v in list(ds)]
```

printing `els` for a sample execution gives:

```
[[0, 1], [4, 1], [12, 0], [16, 0], [1, 1], [10, 0], [3, 1], [2, 1]]
```

**Note:** you might need to experiment with the buffer sizes for the shuffle at the end of the `ds` definition.

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I was looking for, I need to show all samples with y == 1 on every epoch, however only some of the y == 0 samples. So in this example, each epoch would have all 5 of the y == 1 samples however only 3 of the y == 0 samples. For a total of 8 samples. This did get me thinking however, can I initially split the data into a positive and negative dataset, then shuffle and subsample the negative dataset and then concatenate them together. I tried doing this, however for some reason shuffle does not work here.. https://pastebin.com/eFsF7BHA

Comment: Ah, that's quite the different problem from what I understood :) I believe there's a way though.

Comment: @Chris see my new answer

Comment: Oof! my bad, that pastebin almost works - I just did not assign the dataset back to dataset after shuffling. Which is why it was not shuffling. Embarrassing

Comment: Thanks, that is now exactly what I was looking for. How will the shuffle buffer size affect things? The docs for shuffle say `For perfect shuffling, a buffer size greater than or equal to the full size of the dataset is required.`

Comment: I believe shuffling is implemented as something on the line of "fill the buffer with elements, pick a random location, extract that value and add in a new sample to replace it". Since the input to shuffle is a all-positives-first dataset, if the buffer is too small you'll end up with positives-only in the beginning, which is not great for training.